# Is there any method to store class objects through memcached in c?

Tags: c, memcached

I'm trying to use memcached concept in an application rather than using DB to reduce DB usage. Now i want to store a complete class object through memcahed. how do i need use memcached to store class object?

```
struct callcontext

  int sessId;
  char reqtype[5];
cc;                    // structure

 memcached_server_st *server = NULL;
 memcached_st *memc;
 memcached_return rc;

 int sess = 9840661;
 char temp[10];
 int i;
 cc.sessId=9840661;
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    scanf("%c",cc.reqtype[i]);
 snprintf(temp,sizeof(temp),"%d",sess);
 char *key = temp;
 char *value ; 

 char *retrieved_value;
 size_t value_length;
 uint32_t flags;

 memcpy(value,(const unsigned char*)&cc,sizeof(cc));

rc = memcached_set(memc, key, strlen(key), value, strlen(value), (time_t)0, (uint32_t)0); // storing into memcached
```

Comment: initially i tried with structure.

Comment: The posted code will not compile is this your actual code? If so try to wrap your structure definition into braces {}

Comment: Also you never allocate memory for `value` so your `memcpy` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yastanub it is not actual code. just a snippet. is there any way of storing object through this ? Do you have any method to help me out ?

Comment: not many will be able/willing to help you if you do not provide sufficient information. Whats the roblem with the posted code? What does it do and what should it do instead, whats your exact problem? SO is not really the kind of forum you are attending to ask for "how to do this and that" but rather "i want to do that and tried this and stumbled about this specific problem i need help with"